# Go: print variables with gdb

Tags: gdb, go

In this program, how can break execution with the debugger and print the value of i?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        x := "abc"
        i := 3
        fmt.Println(i)
        fmt.Println(x)
}
```

I can't print i. However I can print x:

```
go build test.go
gdb test  
[...]Reading symbols from /home/ned/test...done.
(gdb) br 9
(gdb) run
(gdb) p i
No symbol "i" in current context.
(gdb) p x
$1 = "abc"
```

Comment: It sounds like the variable `i` probably got optimized out of existence by the compiler. Did you try a debug build?

Comment: @sblon how can I make a debug build?

Comment: @SCL run `go build -gcflags '-N'` to disable optimisations.

Comment: @sblon, that was it, thank you. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @sblom please do it, not for the points but because it helps keep SO clean and readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the variable i probably got optimized out of existence by the compiler. Did you try a debug build?

You can use `go build -gcflags '-N'`.