# Golang debug using GDB?

Tags: go, gdb

I got 2 questions about GDB + golang?

```
1) Go build GCC flags
```

when I run "go build" , which gcc flags do the Go builder use to build a program?  The build value is same as the "GOGCCFLAGS" set in the go envionment?

```
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
```

because I don't see any "-g" or "-g3" flags for adding code symbol. If yes, how could the symbol table be compiled ?

2) How to print a value in GDB
    I followed the tutorial here [GDB debug go tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/gdb), but it seems the value is not what I set.

[image: The value print 1, while actual is 1024]

By the way, I noticed there is a post about it [gdb debug go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693831/go-print-variables-with-gdb?rq=1)
   However, doesn't work for me either.
[image: the value is not what I set]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go does not work well with GDB and one of the known problems is the printing of  values.

More details can be found [here](https://golang.org/doc/gdb).

Comment: Thanks, what's the option instead of GDB?

Comment: there is no other option - have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492509/does-any-golang-interactive-debugger-exist/23387017#23387017)

Comment: @python - Delve (https://github.com/go-delve/delve)

Answer (score 15):

Golang now works well with GDB

Here is an example golang app `gdbtest`

```
- gdbtest/
  - main.go
```

Take the following example **main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    x string
    i int
    f float64
}

func main() {
    x := "abc"
    i := 3
    fmt.Println(i)
    fmt.Println(x)

    ms := &MyStruct{
        x: "cba",
        i: 10,
        f: 11.10335,
    }
    fmt.Println(ms)
}
```

Save that to **main.go**. Then compile with the follwing `gcflag` flag.

`go build -gcflags "-N"`

Open gdb with your newly built golang app

```
gdb gdbtest
# or 
gdb <PROJECT_NAME>
```

You now have full control of gdb. For example, add a breakpoint with `br <linenumber>` command, then execute the app with `run`

```
(gdb) br 22
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2311: file /go/src/github.com/cevaris/gdbtest/main.go, line 22.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /go/src/github.com/cevaris/gdbtest/gdbtest
3
abc

Breakpoint 1, main.main () at /go/src/github.com/cevaris/gdbtest/main.go:22
22              fmt.Println(ms)
(gdb)
```

Now you can print all the local variables

```
(gdb) info locals
i = 3
ms = 0x20819e020
x = 0xdb1d0 "abc"
```

Even get access to the pointers

```
(gdb) p ms
$1 = (struct main.MyStruct *) 0x20819e020
(gdb) p *ms
$2 = {x = 0xdb870 "cba", i = 10, f = 11.103350000000001}
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is outdated. 
Golang currently works with GDB (including locals) if you build with the flags `-gcflags=all="-N -l"`, as described on the [official documentation](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)